# Why do I need to create a DateTime service which returns DateTime.Now instead of using DateTime.Now directly?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, datetime, .net-core

I have been watching Jason Taylor presentation about Clean Architecture with ASP.NET Core (timing 35:52)

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dK4Yb6-LxAk&t=2134s&ab_channel=GOTOConferences

And he created a `DateTimeService` which returns `DateTime.Now` and registered via `AddTransient` method, he suggests using it instead of using `DateTime.Now` directly because in this case he doesn't have a dependency on the machine clock.

It's not clear to me why he doesn't have a dependency in this case, could you please explain how it works?

Comment: Without bothering to watch: probably so that you can inject an alternative implementation into unit tests, allowing you to control what value is returned from `Now`.

Comment: Try to write tests for this function: `return DateTime.Now.AddDays(amountOfDays);`

Comment: Testing time behavior in your code, eg testing periodic events or timeouts, would be very hard without a way to change the time seen by your code. With `DateTime.Now` it's impossible to fast-forward time for eg 60 seconds to check whether a timeout works

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you were ever going to implement a different way for getting the current time all you would need to do is create a new implementation for your `IDateTimeService` instead of changing every single instance of `DateTime.Now` in your project.

An example would be to create a service that obtains the time with an external request or to easily create a mock for unit tests so you can properly assert results that are dependent on the date and time.

Answer (score 1):

I believe MS has created [ISystemClock](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.internal.isystemclock?view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0) specifically for this purpose.

Comment: On that page it does specifically say that it's for internal use by the framework so they may remove it later and it shouldn't be used in user code.

Comment: Nevertheless, it is public not internal, and in practice is used by everybody.